How to convert PoA to nPOS and POS?
I am using Substrate parachain template from here.
How I can change it consensus from PoA to:

nPoS
PoS (pure PoS not nPoS)


I crafted a tutorial here for you to convert your default Substrate PoA template to NPOS: https://github.com/openguild-labs/substrate-npos
or this: https://github.com/kaichaosun/substrate-stencil
For PoS, I think it is similar to nPoS but you get rid of the nominator and nomination pool.
